# If $\mathcal C\subseteq C_b(E)$ is an algebra, $fe^{-\varepsilon f^2}$ can be approximated by functions from $\mathcal C$

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, banach-algebras

Let $E$ be a complete separable metric space, $\mathcal C\subseteq C_b(E)$ be a point-separating$^1$ algebra$^2$, $\mu_i$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal B(E))$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

We know that there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $\mu_i(K^c)<\varepsilon$. Let $f\in C_b(E)$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, $\{\left.g\right|_K:g\in\mathcal C\}$ is dense in $C(K)$ and hence there is a $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal C$ with $$\sup_{x\in K}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag1.$$

> I would like to show$^3$ $$(\mu_1-\mu_2)f\le c\varepsilon\tag2$$ for some $c\ge0$.

I've found a proof which considers $(\mu_1-\mu_2)fe^{-\varepsilon f^2}$. They claim that "since $\mathcal C$ is an algebra, $f_ne^{-\varepsilon f_n^2}$ can be approximated by functions from $\mathcal C$ and so $(\mu_1-\mu_2)f_ne^{-\varepsilon f_n^2}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

> Why does this claim hold? Why does it follow that $f_ne^{-\varepsilon f_n^2}$ can be approximated by functions from $\mathcal C$?

---

$^1$ i.e. for all $x,y\in E$, there is a $f\in\mathcal C$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)$.

$^2$ i.e. $1\in\mathcal C$, $\alpha f\in\mathcal C$ for all $f\in\mathcal C$ and $g+h,gh\in\mathcal C$ for all $g,h\in\mathcal C$.

$^3$ For simplicity, write $$\nu h:=\int h\:{\rm d}\nu$$ whenever $\nu$ is a signed finite measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $h\in\mathcal L^1(\nu)$.

Comment: Aren't you missing some sort of assumption linking the $\mu_i$, $\mathcal{C}$ and $f$? When $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are different Dirac measures at distinct points, the result seems to fail...

Comment: @Mindlack I previously wrote $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C(K)$, but it should be $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal C$. Does that resolve your concern?

Comment: Not yet. If each $\mu_i$ is a Dirac at a different point, then the conclusion has no reason to hold. Perhaps you want the measures to be equal on $K$ or something?

Comment: @Mindlack why don't you post this as an answer?

Comment: Because it’s not really an answer, is it? I’m just pointing out that the statement is unsatisfactory...