# How can we show that $\int_Bfe^{-\varepsilon f^2}\:{\rm d}\mu\le\frac c{\sqrt\varepsilon}\mu(B)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, exponential-function

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a probability space, $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be bounded and $\mathcal E$-measurable, $B\in\mathcal E$ and $\varepsilon>0$. How can we show that $$\int_Bfe^{-\varepsilon f^2}\:{\rm d}\mu\le\frac c{\sqrt\varepsilon}\mu(B)\tag1,$$ where $c:=\sup_{x\ge0}xe^{-x^2}$?

The supremum in the definition of $c$ is attained at $1/\sqrt2$. Maybe we need to assume $\varepsilon\le1$, but even then I absolutely don't get how $(1)$ is obtained. It looks like Markov's inequality might be applied, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put $x=\sqrt {\epsilon} |f(y)|$ in the inequaloity $xe^{-x^{2}} \leq c$. You get $|f(y)| e^{-\epsilon f(y)^{2}} \leq \frac c {\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ Now integrate over $B$.

Comment: I'm ashamed. How could I don't see that? Do you also know how the "approximation argument" works here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3882834/47771?